# Is it possible to find the address of the end of an array with a reference to the n+1th element?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, array-pointer

I need to know when the pointer went through the whole array -> is on the first position behind it.
Examplecode in c:

```
unsigned int ar[10];
char *pointer = (char*) ar;
while(pointer != (char*) &ar[10]){
*pointer++ = 0xff
}
```

Would this example work to set every element of the array to 0xffffffff?

Comment: You probably tried and know the answer to the question as asked. So what is the question you actually want answered? Something like "Why?"

Comment: Did you mean to have the pointer point at `ar` or what?

Comment: @Yunnosch Just because something works does not mean it is valid or does not cause UB.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 True, and discussing those concepts is important. However OP should ask what they mean, precisely because of what you point out. And judjng from the answer, this does NOT work or even seem to. So that "something works" you are referring to is probably something else, which OP also does not mention or show. Like: "Tried, fails, why?" or "Tried something similar but functionally different, you know what I mean, succeeds, why?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with raw binary, I'd recommend to use an unsigned character type such as `uint8_t` instead of `char`, since the latter has implementation-defined signedness.

Then there are two special rules in C you can utilize:

C11 6.3.2.3/7

> When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type,
> the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object. Successive increments of the
> result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the object.

This allows us to inspect or modify the raw binary contents of any type in C by using a character pointer. So you can indeed set every byte of the integer array to 0xFF using a character pointer.

The other special rule is hidden inside how the additive operators work, since the [] operator is just syntactic sugar around + and dereference. C11 6.5.6/8, emphasis mine:

> If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, **or one past the last element of the array object**, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

This allows us to check the address 1 `int` beyond the end of the array.

*However* converting between a character type pointer and an `int` pointer creates misaligned pointers and that (at least in theory) invokes undefined behavior and possibly instruction traps. So you can't just cast the character pointer to an integer pointer and compare.

So the completely correct way would be to increase the character pointer by `sizeof(int)` then set 4 bytes each lap in the loop.

Meaning that the following is an well-defined (but cumbersome & hard-to-read) way of setting all bytes in the array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main (void)
{
  unsigned int arr[10];
  
  for(uint8_t* i = (uint8_t*)arr; (unsigned int*)i != &arr[10]; i+=sizeof(unsigned int))
  {
    i[0] = 0xFF;
    i[1] = 0xFF;
    i[2] = 0xFF;
    i[3] = 0xFF;
  }
  
  for(size_t i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
    printf("%X\n", arr[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: So why the downvote? I'm only explaining what works and what doesn't in the OP's code. I never suggested that you should write horrid code like this in real programs.

Comment: Strange, I countered ;)

Comment: You can always cast the integer pointer to char pointer though, so the last part is not strictly necessary.

Comment: @Lundin I used a char pointer because that was the type of the buffer I want to write to. For the example code: I did not know that a char is signed character type and thought it would not matter. Thank you for your help! :D

Answer (score 1):

The principle is right but you forgot to initialize the pointer and are incrementing it in the wrong place. Rather use

```
unsigned int ar[10];
unsigned char *pointer = (unsigned char *)ar;
unsigned char *end = (unsigned char *)&ar[10];
while (pointer != end) { 
    *pointer++ = 0xff;
}
```

if you increment the pointer in the comparison, then you will not set the first byte and will write one byte past the limit.

But never reinvent the wheel. There is a function in `<string.h>` for this:

```
unsigned int ar[10];
memset(ar, 0xff, 10 * sizeof (int));

// or if a static array,
memset(ar, 0xff, sizeof ar);
```

On the other hand, if you really want to set the `unsigned int`s to UINT_MAX, then you could be explicit:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ar[i] = UINT_MAX; // or you could use `-1` as well, as it is guaranteed to result in `UINT_MAX` after conversion.
}
```

Comment: In all fairness, `memset` is a bit blunt. Suppose you need to set every int to a fixed 32 bit value. The most correct way in the generic case might be to use a `for` loop (but that's too easy! :) ).

Comment: Why is the increment in the wrong place? I thought of it like incrementation of the control variable in a for loop.

Comment: @Nemora it is not a control variable, it is the *indexing* variable. But you can increment it only *after* you have done the indexing

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Oh you are right. I have not given much thought to the example code. ^^